# flatpak in a script, how to auto answer "Use this remote?"

Tags: command-line, scripts, flatpak

When trying to install flapaks in a script,

$ flatpak install program_I_am_installing

I get prompted with

Found similar ref(s) for 'program_I_am_installing' in remote 'flathub' (subsystem).

Use this remote [Y/n]:

The default goes to "n" when running the script since I have no way of entering Y withing the script.

I tried giving flatpak the full Application ID, but that didn't stop the question from being asked.

I'd either like to find how to answer the question Y in the script or know how to more specificaly state the program name so this question isn't asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple option that may help get silent installation

- Include REMOTE source explicitly

  ```
  flatpak install [OPTION...] [REMOTE] REF
  flatpak install flathub <your-program>
  ```
- Assume YES like with `apt-get` or Non-Interactive

  > **`-y`, `--assumeyes`**
  >
  > Automatically answer yes to all questions (or pick the most prioritized answer). This is useful for automation.
  >
  > **`--noninteractive`**
  >
  > Produce minimal output and avoid most questions. This is suitable for use in non-interactive situations, e.g. in a build script.

  ```
  flatpak install -y --noninteractive <your-program>
  ```

**Reference:** [flatpak docs](http://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/flatpak-command-reference.html#flatpak-install)

Comment: This fixed all of them except one that looks like it didn't have a default defined or possible the name I gave wasn't unique enough.